# Angular 7 Component Inheritance using a global injector

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular7

I've been using the approach described in an [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/06/17/angular-how-to-simplify-components-with-typescript-inheritance/#comment-38395) to simplify extending components without needing to provide all the dependencies in the `super()` call. However this has stopped working in Angular 7 with Typescript 3.

So what's happening is that after bootstrapping, I'm trying to store the injector in a service and afterwards I try to retrieve it.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  // Store module's injector in the AppInjector class
  console.log('Expected #1: storing app injector');
  AppInjector.setInjector(ref.injector);
})
```

and then in the base component I fetch the stored injector

```
export class BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Expected #2: retrieving stored injector');
    const injector = AppInjector.getInjector();
  }
}
```

However looking at the console, the order is reversed – first the `BaseComponent`'s constructor is called whichafter the promise of `boostrapModule()` is resolved.

I'm not sure if bootstrapping is behaving differently now in Angular 7, as the console logs hint. The very same solution used to work in Angular 6 with Typescript 2, but with version 7 it has stopped working. Here's a stackblitz of the broken app based on the MSDN article: https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-7

So the fundamental question is – **how to guarantee that `AppInjector.setInjector()` happens before `AppInjector.getInjector()`**?

Comment: Would that bother you to do it in the bootstraped component ? Seems to work : https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-7-mzhem6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Use AppModule constructor https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-7-dfd2wr

Comment: Thanks! Both suggestions help circumvent the problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have set the injector service in AppModule and that mean I will inject Injector and set it in the constractor of AppModule and store the injector service in global object

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(injector:Injector){
  // Store module's injector in the AppInjector class
  console.log('Expected #1: storing app injector');
  AppInjector.setInjector(injector);
  }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-7-dfd2wr)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Althought I went for storing the injector in the `AppComponent` instead of `AppModule` as per trichetriche's comment, I will mark your answer as accepted, as it works too. Feels somewhat hacky to do so, but as long as it works, right? :)

Comment: Both are acceptable but if the you extend `AppComponent` with base class `AppModule` will be the place to set injector because `AppModule` is create before `AppComponent`.

Comment: Can you send the full final example to plunkr?

Comment: @rsb2097  this live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-angular-7-dfd2wr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbase.component.ts