# Angular 7 testing with inheritance and global injector

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, frontend, karma-jasmine, angular7

I'm starting a new project in Angular 7 and have a base component to center some of my global variables and services. As the project can grow quite big, I chose this approach to avoid a massive amount of imports at the beginning of each component and also at super() calls.

To do this, I implemented the approach described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/06/17/angular-how-to-simplify-components-with-typescript-inheritance/), where an external class stores a dependency injector to be used in the base component. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185211/angular-7-component-inheritance-using-a-global-injector), a modification had to be made to comply with Angular 7 (the injector had to be initialized at the AppModule). (See plunker below)

This works fine for running the project, the problem comes when I try to run unit tests (using karma-jasmine). Since the AppInjector is initialized in the module, the testing run does not initialize it. Then, since my base component tries to call a function of the injector, it breaks.

If anyone has any solution for this, either by modifying the test structure or the AppInjector itself, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a plunker with all the code involved. The example is a global notification component using primeng toast module and a global notification service in the base component. (I couldn't get the plunker to work properly, some sort of MIME type error, but the code is all there)

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7v5nB8cORWsnpPAL?preview

When I run ng test, this is the error I get:

```
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 10.0.0) AppComponent should create the app FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
            at NotificationsComponent.BaseComponent (http://localhost:9876/src/app/components/base.component.ts?:22:50)
            at new NotificationsComponent (http://localhost:9876/src/app/components/utils/notifications/notifications.component.ts?:17:13)
            at createClass (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20716:1)
            at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20595:1)
            at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:21821:1)
            at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:22137:1)
            at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:22056:1)
            at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:21849:1)
            at createRootView (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:21735:1)
            at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:22767:1)
        Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
            at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:831:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:896:1
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:423:1)
            at AsyncTestZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:698:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:317:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:422:1)
            at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:195:1)
            at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:601:1)
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:35:21)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:391:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:289:1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tests you can get the injector from the `TestBed`. So you can initialize your `AppInjector` in the `beforeEach` like all other things. Just do it before the `createComponent` call so it is ready.

Here is the changed code from your Plunker sample:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
                ToastModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                NotificationsComponent
            ]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            AppInjector.setInjector(TestBed.get(Injector));
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
            app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        });
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! As you may have noticed, I'm new with unit testing / karma, so if you have some good references to study it would be most welcome! Cheers